# Error: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/utils'

Tags: angular

`Error: Cannot find module @angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/utils`

Does anyone have an idea about how to solve this?

It shows up when I run this: `ionic cordova run android –device`,
but when I run `ionic serve`, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like error in your ionic-plugin so remove this plugin
with this

> Cordova plugin remove 'name-of-plugin'

and again try to install this plugin

> ionic cordova plugin
> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@latest
> ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-camera

and
you can remove the node_module folder of the working directory 
and again install all dependencies

> npm install 
> npm install package name

I hope it helps you